# how to store HashMap in ArrayList then to String[]

Tags: android, dictionary, arraylist

here are my items

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> c_tmp= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
 public HashMap<String,String>mapa=new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] name_Val = null;
```

Can anyone help me how to store in a String[] the following line name_Val

```
name_Val = (String[]) c_tmp.toArray(new String[c_tmp.size()]);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,name_Val);
```

I get this exception
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type Ljava/util/HashMap; cannot be stored in destination array of type [Ljava/lang/String;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to flatten a map, which is a set of key/value pairs into a flat list of values.  What's supposed to happen to the keys here?  Your `c_tmp` variable is a list of `HashMap`s, which is probably not what you want.

If you only want the values from the map and you want to discard the keys, do this:

```
List<String> strings = yourHashMap.values()
```

You can then convert the `List` into an array should you so desire.

Comment: I can add the keys to the values, but it asks to do something like List<String> strings=(List<string>)hasmymap.values()

Comment: I think you should edit your question to include some sample data and what you want the results to look like because it's still not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to write down either name or a number and to show a contact below

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is, you can simply use a `HashMap<String,String>` Data type as map has the property of adding `values` for a `unique key`

After you are done with storing the Data in the `hashmap` you can use the `Iterator` to iterate and get all keys from the `HashMap` and thus the `Values` from all those keys which shall be Stored in an `ArrayList` , and then converting it to your `String Array` would not be a problem for you.